# re.search not matching the byte string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pexpect

I have a string object got from pexpect's `session.before`.

From this I am trying `re.search` for getting the device id using the below regular expression. But it is not matching.

```
print (str(sess.before))
b'\r\n* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *\r\n* daemon started successfully *\r\n353651\tdevice\r\n\r\n\r\n'

device_id = re.search ('([0-9a-zA-Z]+)[\t ]+device', str(sess.before))
print (device_id)
None
```

Comment: @Wiktor: kinda-sorta. The problem was mostly with the `str()` call being a very wrong way of converting a `bytes` object to a string.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I just wonder why OP has `b'\r\n*...'` and not `"b'\\r\\n*...'"` then? If you are sure there are at least 2 issues, then yes, it can be reopened.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: the `print()` call masks the issue; in effect  `print(bytesobject)` is already using `str()` so the `str()` in the first line is entirely redundant. `str(sess.before)` *does* return `"b'\\r\\n*...'"`, but when you then *print* that...

Comment: @MartijnPieters I understand that, but still that means OP should have written `"b'\\r\\n*...'"` if `str()` were applied twice to the bytes object. Ashwin, please let know if you just needed to add the `b` prefix to the regex to solve the issue or if you also had to modify the way you passed the input to the regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: `str()` applied to a `str()` does not then use `repr()`, it just returns the string unchanged. Don't fall into the reverse `repr()` trap here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: you seem to be confusing what the Python REPL echoes for `str(bytesobject)` (which uses `print(repr(...))`) with what `print(str(bytesobject))` outputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `str()` call converts your `bytes` object to a *representation*. Tabs will be represented as the character sequence `'\'` and `'t'`, not an actual tab:

```
>>> str(b'\t')
"b'\\t'"
```

Don't hammer your bytestring to a string like that. Either *decode* from bytes to a string, or just use a `bytes` regular expression:

```
device_id = re.search(b'([0-9a-zA-Z]+)[\t ]+device', sess.before)
```

Now `device_id` is the match object; you may want to call `.group(1)` on that:

```
>>> import re
>>> before = b'\r\n* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *\r\n* daemon started successfully *\r\n353651\tdevice\r\n\r\n\r\n'
>>> re.search(b'([0-9a-zA-Z]+)[\t ]+device', before)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(89, 102), match=b'353651\tdevice'>
>>> re.search(b'([0-9a-zA-Z]+)[\t ]+device', before).group(1)
b'353651'
```